# How to sort numbers in C# XML?

Tags: c#, xml, sorting

I have the following xml code:

```
    <highscore>
  <score>
    <naam>Pipo</naam>
    <punten>200</punten>
  </score>
  <score>
    <naam>Harry</naam>
    <punten>400</punten>
  </score>
</highscore>
```

How can I sort by "punten"? So the highest number is on top?

Thanks!!

Comment: Might want to post what your current c# code looks like now

Comment: Or at least provide an example of the desired result. Is it XML? A list of the scores? A completely different data structure altogether?

Comment: It need to show the highest highscores. I have a list of the scores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var xml=@" <highscore>
  <score>
    <naam>Pipo</naam>
    <punten>200</punten>
  </score>
  <score>
    <naam>Harry</naam>
    <punten>400</punten>
  </score>
</highscore>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var orderedScoreElements = 
      doc.Root
         .Elements("score")
         .OrderByDescending(e => (int)e.Element("punten"))
         .ToList();
```

and to rewrite the doc in order:

```
doc.Root.RemoveNodes();
doc.Root.Add(orderedScoreElements);
```

Comment: Thanks but were I need to put the: doc.Root.RemoveNodes();
doc.Root.Add(orderedScoreElements); ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var xml = @"<highscore>
  <score>
    <naam>Pipo</naam>
    <punten>200</punten>
  </score>
  <score>
    <naam>Harry</naam>
    <punten>400</punten>
  </score>
</highscore>";

var x = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var elementsInOrder = x.Descendants("score").OrderByDescending(el=>Convert.ToInt32(el.Element("punten").Value));
```