# Sort list numericallyC#

Tags: c#, xml, sorting

I have a xml file:

```
<highscore>
  <score>
    <naam>rake</naam>
    <punten>100</punten>
  </score>
  <score>
    <naam>john</naam>
    <punten>200</punten>
</score>
</highscore>
```

and the code put the values in a list and to show:

```
public Highscores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        XmlNode node = this.xmlbeheer.Open("Highscores/Highscores.xml");
        List<Score> scores = new List<Score>();


        foreach (XmlNode score in node.ChildNodes)
        {

            if (score.Name == "score")
            {
                Score s = new Score();
                foreach (XmlNode child in score.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (child.Name == "naam")
                    {
                       s.Naam = child.InnerText;
                    }
                    if (child.Name == "punten")
                    {
                        s.Punten = child.InnerText;
                    }                     
                }
                scores.Add(s);
            }
        }

        foreach (Score s in scores)
        {
            if (n < 5)
            {
                Label naam = new Label();
                naam.Top = 10 + 23 * n;
                naam.Text = (n + 1) + ". " + s.Naam;
                naam.Left = 0;
                pnlScores.Controls.Add(naam);

                Label punten = new Label();
                punten.Top = 10 + 23 * n;
                punten.Text = s.Punten;
                punten.Left = 140;
                pnlScores.Controls.Add(punten);
            }
            n++;
        }
    }
```

But my question is how can I sort the "punten" numerically form high to low?
I saw a lot things on the internet but I didn't understand them :(

I really appreciate the answers!!

Thanks!!

Comment: I answered something almost identical to this yesterday.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231446/select-top-5-records-from-xml-with-c-sharp/17231588#17231588

Comment: you need to take a couple steps back and study the basics of c# and generics before trying to apply it to xml files

Comment: Youly code only added one item to the List!!!

Comment: @Scott No need to insult the OP. Also, his code does iterate over the XML.

Comment: Suspicious match (homework?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240317/how-to-sort-numbers-in-c-sharp-xml

Comment: @MikePrecup - its not an insult, its a suggestion,  see my answer

Comment: @Tormod Same guy posted both, so I'm guessing it isn't homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in-place sort `scores` if you want, using [`List.Sort(Comparison<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
scores.Sort((a, b) => int.Parse(a.Punten).CompareTo(int.Parse(b.Punten)));
```

Note that because `Punten` appears to be a string, you need to convert it to an `int` to compare properly.

If you change your code to make `Punten` an int, the sorting code would simplify to:

```
scores.Sort((a, b) => a.Punten.CompareTo(b.Punten));
```

What's happening here is that we are supplying a comparison function with which the sort will compare pairs of items to determine the required order.

`(a, b)` in the code above specifies two parameters of the element type of the list to compare. We just need to compare their `Punten` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since `punten` is a string you must convert it to an `int`, you can then use [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916.aspx) and do this:

```
 var sortedByPunten = scores.OrderByDescending(s => Int32.Parse(s.punten));
```

Comment: The line `s.Punten = child.InnerText;` indicates that it's a string.

Comment: @MikePrecup - good spot. He'd have to either change it to an int or perform a cast.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `OrderByDescending` LINQ method and in that method convert your string to an integer (e.g. using `Convert.ToInt32`):

```
var scores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Punten));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're only adding one item to your list

```
Score s = new Score();
                foreach (XmlNode child in score.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (child.Name == "naam")
                    {
                       s.Naam = child.InnerText;
                    }
                    if (child.Name == "punten")
                    {
                        s.Punten = child.InnerText;
                    } 
                 scores.Add(s); // <-- move here and delete the one under this
                }
                scores.Add(s); // <-- see adding s to the List s outside the loop
```

after fixing that to something like google or there are several good answer here c# sort List.   I really think you need to take a minute to learn a little more of c# basics , right now you have it written so you have to hard code every node of the xml in your c# ,  whats the point of even reading the XML file?

Comment: I'm guessing OP posted a sample of his file, not the whole thing.  But thanks for posting an answer :)

Comment: I get that , but then again maybe not - OP is asking how to sort a generic List,  which leads me to believe OP is pretty fresh into programming